# Is it safer or better to separate tables to different databases

Tags: sql, database

So I have a database where I want to store all the tables including those about members. But recently I was searching online and saw that I think someone said that [it wasn't a good idea](https://www.esecurityplanet.com/hackers/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-attacks.html) so should I or should I not separate very important SQL tables to different databases

Comment: Moving data to a different db is not how to stop sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the requirement. If you make separate database for few tables then you need to manage more consistency. and important thing is that, we cant prevent SQL Injection bby making it separate.

Micro service concept suggest to make separate database for each micro service. But in that case you will have module wise structure and independent design.

So, i suggest to go with single database if you have relational tables.